# What happened to gods share of the virgin girls in Numbers 31

Tags: numbers, sacrifice, offering

In the book of Numbers, a great many bulls, goats rams etc... are killed and burned as sacrifices to God.

However, in the Book of Numbers (chaoter 31; verses 25 through 42) some human women are also pledged as sacrifices to the lord.

Is the implication that the Israelites killed the young Midianite women?

Comment: Which verse are you referring to?

Comment: the question requires clarification. It appears to refer to 31:35-37  "The persons were sixteen thousand, of which the Lord’s tribute was thirty-two persons." (vs 15 speaks of the person as "women who had not known man by lying with him. "

Comment: Samuel Muldoon welcome to BHse. Please take the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the group works. One guideline is to include enough info so that people don't have to guess at what you are referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am correct that the OP refers to Num. 31:32-41 then it does describe 32 virgin women taken as war booty and then set aside for the Lord, though not as "sacrifices" as mentioned in the OP.

> The booty remaining of the spoil that the men of war took was: six
> hundred and seventy-five thousand sheep, seventy-two thousand cattle,
> sixty-one thousand asses, and *thirty-two thousand persons in all,
> women who had not known man by lying with him...The persons [given to the warriors] were sixteen
> thousand, of which the Lord’s tribute was thirty-two persons. And Moses gave the tribute, which was the offering for the Lord, to Elea′zar the priest, as the Lord commanded Moses.*

The OP apparently asks what happened to these women who were set aside as "the Lord's tribute." The text is clear that there were not to be killed in the battle or its aftermath. Nor can we accept the idea that they were murdered afterward, whether as sacrifices to the Lord or otherwise. They may have been redeemed in accordance with Lev 27:2. But in any case, **their most likely fate would be to become slaves devoted to serving in some way at the Tabernacle.**

---

*Note: The OP has provided a brief answer to his own question. It cites a verse which I overlooked. "the Lord’s tribute was thirty-two persons. 41 And Moses gave the tribute, which was the offering for the Lord, to Elea′zar the priest, as the Lord commanded Moses."*

Comment: V35 says 32,000 virgins, not just 32.

Comment: That is the total captured. 16k given to the warriors (presumably another 16k to non-warriors) and 32 persons as "the Lord's tribute."

Comment: " The persons were sixteen thousand, [half of the total)]of which the Lord’s tribute was thirty-two persons. 41 And Moses gave the tribute, which was the offering for the Lord, to Elea′zar the priest, as the Lord commanded Moses.

Comment: This answer is not Biblically accurate.  Consider Leviticus 21:14.  "A widow, or a divorced woman, or profane, or an harlot, these shall he not take: but **he shall take a virgin of his own people to wife.**". Foreigners were not marriage material for the priests or Levites.  You may wish to update your conclusions.

Comment: you make a good point, but do you think that priests were never corrupt in this area? I'll fix the answer though. Thank you.

Comment: See Ezra 10 :1-5 for evidence that priests and levites did take foreign wives.

Answer (score 1):

The 32 young women became the property of a priest named Elea′zar

Numbers chapter 31 verses 40-42.

Comment: The ases (donkeys) also were not sacrificed/killed

Comment: but he IS the author ;-)  And it does answer the primary question.

Answer (score 0):

No, they probably served (read: were either forced or offered to, those not accepting being replaced by those among those assigned to others) as chaste women in the Temple, weaving the veil and cords and the priest's garments, in a similar way to how nuns are chaste and serve various functions in the Church like fashion vestments for the priest. Why chaste? Simply because it's always been tied up with the purity required for service of God in the more solemn circumstances. When David sought the Bread of the Presence, when he was in danger of starving, he was to be "[ritually] pure, especially from women," as well as the men with him. The early church insisted on the preference of virginity over marriage, and thus the preference for elders being unmarried which endures to this day. Even St. Paul was chaste and wished others would be, since it allows - specifically - for a more fully offering of oneself to God, inside of God and, also, a wife. So the reasons for chastity are not exactly mysterious, number one.

The Talmud mentions the women who weave the temple veil; Luke mentions Elizabeth not departing from the Temple day or night, meaning widows might have served such a role of service.The Old Testament mentions women who, like the priests, in some way, "serve" at the Temple, and also writes of them in a context where, when men had relations with them, it was considered a scandal and antithetical to their state (similar to how a nun being caught having relationsh with someone - anyone - would be a scandal today); St. Paul, again, seems to speak of "widows" and even "virgins" in a somewhat technical sense, even in the New Covenant context, but it's hard to tell - and of course we know there were what are now called 'nuns', or people who deliberately remained chaste in favor of a life of prayer, in the early Church, too.

And we also have data from the early second century work called the Pre-Gospel of James, regarding the fact that Mary, their from her infancy, had to leave the Temple when she reached the age of menstruation - or, ritual uncleanness - meaning there were virgins who served some function at the Temple that isn't really defined anwhere in detail, but is alluded to and sometimes explicitly mentioned in various works we have no positive reason to doubt given the in-passing nature of them.

Lastly, we have the perhaps more pertinent example of Jepthah's daughter: he promised God the first thing that walked out the door of his house, when he returned from defeating the Ammorites, he would sacrifice to God. To his dismay, his daughter ran to greet him instead of some animal. Yet it's hardly imaginable that a good faithful follower of Yahweh would think Yahweh would approve of human sacrifice, so arbitrary,  grusome, and so forth, as it is. Rather, it seems that his "offering" was to dedicate his daugther as something along the lines of one these Temple women. Similar to *compelling*, due to a vow to God, your daughter today to be a nun - tragic indeed, but not a human sacrifice. This was made even worse given the fact that in this ancient culture, a woman not having children was seen as almost grounds for feeling *suicidally* depressed. In fact, it was viewed a *curse* just as much as a child was a *blessing*. Since the text says she first went to mourn the fact that she wouldn't have children or get married - "mourn her virginity" - ever. Which seems to imply that, like Samson, the "offering"-promise was one of dedication to a life of service or sacrifice (i.e. Samson being a Nazarite- the equivalent to a 'monk,' as these women seem to have been of 'nuns'), since the context determined the meaning of "sacrifice"or "offering" per the case. A sacrifice better than animal sacrifice, but not equivalent to mere human sacrifice, which is *inferior* to a sacrificial life anyway.

It seems the remainder were simply women free to marry and spared for this reason, and perhaps to continue this seed, whereas those dedicated to the priests would, as in the case of Jephthah, be assumed to live a life of sacrifice, namely, Temple service, rather than actually being physically sacrificed - *qua* offered to the priests, and notably "the Lord." One can be "set apart" and "sacrificed" to God without literally being set on fire or stabbed to death - the lives of the saints are one glaring example of both of these - literally being set on fire by the enemies of God (note), or stabbed or crucified to death, but never voluntarily killing themselves or being killed by faithful followers of God.

I for one believe that faithful Israelites would have been just as horrified of Moloch and human sacrifice as faithful Israelites would have been of the Golden Calf. And also that to take sacrifice univocally is a form of argument from silence, and not the argument which respects the silence and listens to some other data from other areas of Scripture and history. Abraham was specifically remembered for the great faith he had, meaning offering your own child in sacrifice out of faithin God was not commonplace - to say the least.